# Is it better to I write only one block for a event and a element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events

I want to know, is there any difference between them? *(performance and being optimized perspective)*

**First way:** writing multiple block for identical event and element

```
$('element').on('click', function(){
    console.log("one");
});

$('element').on('click', function(){
    console.log("two");
});
```

**Second way:** writing all codes into one block

```
$('element').on('click', function(){
    console.log("one");
    console.log("two");
});
```

---

It should be noted in reality there is a lot of more code than codes above. So all I want to know is, should I try to write all codes which are belong to identical event and element in one piece? or it doesn't matter if I write them separately? *(multiple piece)*

Comment: Depends on the purpose of said code. In your very minimal example it would make no sense to separate them.

Answer (score 2):

From a traceability/debugging perspective, I would only allow a single entry point for a given event emission. Yes, there are always exceptions, but if you find the `onClick()` function is growing a bit unwieldy, then refactor those distinct bits out into a separate functions. The result is often that readability and predictability improve:

```
$('element').on('click', function(){
    doSomething();
    AndNowForSomethingCompletelyDifferent();
    yetAnotherThingToDo();
});
```